# Adding different color or texture on the inside of an object

Tags: texturing, materials, objects, color

I made this object out of a half and then I used the mirror modifyer to create the other side. Then I made a copy of the faces for a third seperate mesh that I created for the middle part. What I want to do now is to change the color or add a texture preferably on the inside thats different from the outside. I managed to somewhat do i on the side by creating a copy of the mesh and moving it a little bit to the inside, selecting the faces and I was able to create a seperate color for it. But now I am struggeling for the middle part on the inside because of the curve. Because if I do the same the inside doesn't look smooth. Is there any easier way to do this?

I know you can use UV mapping but in this case it doesn't work because if I select the face is changes the color or texture both side of the face. And creating a copy of the mesh makes the inside look uneven. https://ibb.co/TbFVfHk https://ibb.co/HPZJZ8M
https://ibb.co/9vRG2s2
https://ibb.co/TbGqQMK
[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the solidify modifier?

Comment: There is no reason why UV unrapping the object won't work in this case. Create a black and white mask and use it to drive your shaders: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/748/31447